# How to access geocode coordinates outside for loop?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

This is similar to this question: [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13604851/accessing-array-from-outside-of-geocode-loop). But I still can't work it out. 
I want to get the lat/lng values from my geocoder but I can't access them outside of the if statement. I know that most things are working because I can access the geocode lat/lng values with `console.log()` but I can't get them out. I think this has to do with js scope. If I use the code below I get this error:

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geocode' of undefined".

But If I comment out this part  `var myLoc = codeAddress(addressInput);` I can get the array with `console.log()`.

How can get the loc (or each value) array out?

Here is my code.

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

var addressInput = '<?php 
    echo $_GET["q"]; ? > ';
var loc = [];

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    codeAddress(addressInput);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
    // next line creates asynchronous request
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        // and this is function which processes response
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            loc[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

        console.log(loc);
        // above shows the correct lat/lng values in the console when I comment out the 'myLoc' code below.
    });
    return loc;

}
var myLoc = codeAddress(addressInput);

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: The geocoder is asynchronous, you can't return anything from its callback function, you have to use it in there where/when it is available.  What do you need to use the coordinates for?

Comment: I have a search function where someone enters an address and then I change this address to lat/lng (with the geocode function). Then I want to check these coordinates against a database of stores (with lat/lng coordinates) and get the closest matching coordinates/stores in a list on a another page. Basically I need to send the coordinates from this geocode to another page.

Comment: How are you doing that?  I don't see anything to do that in the posted code.

Comment: The search stuff is sorted (i'm using laravel btw). It's just about feeding these coordinates to the model/controller.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the very first line that gets executed in your code, apart from where you specify the global variables `map`, `loc` etc, is:

```
var myLoc = codeAddress(addressInput);
```

And at that point the `geocoder` which the `codeAddress` function needs hasn't been created.

Given that you almost immediately afterwards, on window load, call `codeAddress` again, I'm not sure of the point of this initial call to it.  Just change your code to:

```
var geocoder, map, myLoc;

var addressInput = '<?php 
    echo $_GET["q"]; ? > ';
var loc = [];

function initialize() {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    myLoc = codeAddress(addressInput);
    console.log(myLoc);
}

function codeAddress(address) {
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            loc[0] = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            loc[1] = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        } else {
            alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
        }

        console.log(loc);
    });
    return loc;
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```